# AWS Cognito, change Account status by CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

Is there a way to change the `Account status` on a user by CLI command?

I know I can resend an email verification with:

```
aws cognito-idp resend-confirmation-code --client-id 54675464564564 --username XXXX@gmail.com
```

Is there are any similar command for what I need?

Comment: What is the expected Account Status you need? Could you detail more the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it was with:

```
aws cognito-idp admin-update-user-attributes --user-pool-id us-east-2_XXXX --username XXXXXXX@NNNN.com  --user-attributes Name="email_verified",Value="false"
```